# Python adding hyperlink to Outlook task through win32com

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I would like to create an hyperlink in the body of a task created through win32com.

This is my code so far:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
outlook_task_item = 3
recipient = "my_email@site.com"
task = outlook.CreateItem(outlook_task_item)
task.Subject = "hello world"
task.Body = "please update the file here"
task.DueDate = dt.datetime.today()
task.ReminderTime = dt.datetime.today()
task.ReminderSet = True
task.Save()
```

I have tried to set the property `task.HTMLBody` but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: Property 'CreateItem.HTMLBody' can not be set.
```

I have also tried

```
task.Body = "Here is the <a href='http://www.python.org'>link</a> I need"
```

but I am not getting a proper hyperlink.

However if I create a task front end in Outlook, I am able to add hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks do not support HTML. Instead, you have to provide RTF.

You can investigate -- but not set -- the RTF of a given task through `task.RTFBody` (and `task.RTFBody.obj` to get a convenient view of it). To use RTF in the body of a task, simply use the `task.Body` property; setting this to a byte array containing RTF will automatically use that RTF in the body. Concretely, to get the body you want, you could let

```
task.Body = rb'{\rtf1{Here is the }{\field{\*\fldinst { HYPERLINK "https://www.python.org" }}{\fldrslt {link}}}{ I need}}'
```

Comment: sweet!!! I did try setting RTFbody without luck indeed. thanks a lot. Quick question, do you know why I am putting something like "c:\üsers\...\documents\..." , the hyperlink send me to "c:\users\...\desktop\... instead?

Comment: just to close the circle, the hyperlink need to be specified with double \\ and if the path is not recognized you are sent to the desktop. so in my case, the path was not recognized and I was sent to the Desktop instead of my documents.

Comment: @GiuseppeBonavita: Note that those would be a standard use case for raw string literals; `r'C:\users\username\documents'` allows you to pass in single backslashes (cf. also the example body in the answer).

Comment: I left the rb prefix to the string, and as reported I was sent to the Desktop folder. then I found out that the two backslash were needed. In my case the body of the message and the link are in an excel file which is processed by pandas. According to what is in the excel file, I want to send a task, possibly with an hyperlink.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try:

```
task.HTMLBody = "Here is the <a href='http://www.python.org'>link</a> I need"
```

this will overwrite data in 'task.Body' to the HTML format provides in 'task.HTMLBody'

so whichever (Body or HTMLBody) is last will be taken as the Body of the mail.